# How did you change the version number of a compilation?

Tags: c++, cmake, blender

when compiling blender my branch is 2.79b, but the output what remains in the

`RELEASE` folder ends up as **Blender 2.79**

I have not tried a solution yet because I do not know exactly what to do, I'm still a novice in compiling software

[image: screensplash blender]
[image: my project folders]

Answer (score 1):

The blender developers use tags to mark specific releases. You can see a list of available tags with `git tag` and checkout a specific tag with `git checkout <tagname>`. Use one of these tags to get the source code matching an official blender release.

To get the source code used to build the official 2.79b release, use `git checkout v2.79b`

Branches are a collection of commits that are separated from other branch commits, usually for development and testing before being accepted to be merged into the master branch. If you want to work with various new features before they are accepted as part of official releases you can checkout one of the branches. You can get a list of available local branches with `git branch`, local branches are ones you have created. For all available branches use `git branch -a`, and use the name after `remotes/origin/` with `git checkout <branchname>`.

As a distributed version control system, git has local and remote branches, you commit changes to a local branch before pushing them back to the remote repository.

Git should be setup to open documentation for you, for example use `git help branch` to see options available for branching. You may also be interested in reading [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to get a better understanding of how git uses branches and tags.

Comment: my previous questions were to clone the correct branch with the correct tags, I have seen that not only did this happen to me, I found compiled from graphical.org which are the same are 2.79b and have some unofficial implementations but the blender and the screen splash says the same as mine, so I guess it's the user's ignorance to configure something in the cmake, I do not think it has anything to do with git or svn

Comment: cd C:\blender-git
git clone git://git.blender.org/blender.git --branch v2.79b

Comment: yes I know, but I do not want to return changes to any remote repository only local

Comment: go that last if I have it very present, I need a lot to know in git and the labels and branches, and of course I'm going to read I still thirst for knowledge

Comment: the answer is very good and I will put it to the test to see if it solves my problem and kills my ignorance and cvolvere in a couple of days with feedback